# Failed to initialize display event receiver

Tags: android, crash

I have made an app which periodically starts a service that retrieves information from a server.

I use an AlarmManager to schedule the service.
This works fine and the app receives the alarm every 30 min.
The app works fine, but after a full night of inactivity -and I start the app, it crashes with the error: 'Failed to initialize display event receiver'.

Else this works perfectly.

I searched this problem for a long time and found others with the same problem, but no solution, yet.

```
Process: it.unipi.iet.portolan.traceroute, PID: 13092
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize display event receiver.  status=-2147483648
at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.nativeInit(Native Method)
at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.<init>(DisplayEventReceiver.java:61)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.<init>(Choreographer.java:695)
at android.view.Choreographer.<init>(Choreographer.java:169)
at android.view.Choreographer.<init>(Choreographer.java:72)
at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:98)
at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:91)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.getAfterMiss(ThreadLocal.java:430)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:65)
at android.view.Choreographer.getInstance(Choreographer.java:194)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:370)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2871)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5141)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: a question: in your service, are you referencing the right context?

Comment: Please add the code where you are getting this error.

Comment: @barq the crash log is not pointing to his code. I also received in with my app on Android 5.1.1. I'm using Crashlytics, but still no idea where it occurred.

Comment: Then provide a minimal setup on how to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Show your relevant code that cause error.

Comment: I hope this can help you! [AlarmManager once per day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703898/schedule-a-timertask-at-specific-time-once-per-day-in-a-service-in-android)

Comment: @Adri please show the minimal code.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Just for some info]

Just for some info, I can't understand why,
The message throws from :

```
frameworks/base/core/jni/android_view_DisplayEventReceiver.cpp:4239:        message.appendFormat("Failed to initialize display event receiver.  status=%d", status);
```

or maybe this

```
frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/DisplayEventDispatcher.cpp:1427:        ALOGW("Failed to initialize display event receiver, status=%d", result);
```

the `status -2147483648 = 0x800000000`

it return from the DisplayEventReceiver:

```
  /* initCheck returns the state of DisplayEventReceiver after construction.*/

status_t initCheck() const;
```

and look at the DisplayEventReceiver.cpp

```
status_t DisplayEventReceiver::initCheck() const {
if (mDataChannel != NULL)
    return NO_ERROR;
return NO_INIT;
}
```

look like the `mDataChannel` is NULL,

the mDataChannel initialized in the constructor

```
DisplayEventReceiver::DisplayEventReceiver() {
    sp<ISurfaceComposer> sf(ComposerService::getComposerService());
    if (sf != NULL) {
        mEventConnection = sf->createDisplayEventConnection();
        if (mEventConnection != NULL) {
            mDataChannel = mEventConnection->getDataChannel();
        }
    }
}
```

so sf SurfaceComposer is NULL or the sf-> createDisplayEventConnection return NULL.

and in the file `./system/core/include/utils/Errors.h`

```
...
NO_ERROR            =0
UNKNOWN_ERROR       = (-2147483647-1), // INT32_MIN value

NO_MEMORY           = -ENOMEM,
INVALID_OPERATION   = -ENOSYS,
BAD_VALUE           = -EINVAL,
BAD_TYPE            = (UNKNOWN_ERROR + 1),
NO_INIT             = -ENODEV,
...
```

seems the status must  `NO_INIT`...

Comment: `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/androidfw/DisplayEventDispatcher.cpp`

Comment: Thanks for all that efforts!