# Schedule a TimerTask at specific time once per day in a service in android

Tags: android, service, timer, android-service, timertask

I have a `TimerTask` object **timerTask**. My code is running but when service gets started initially, my timer task runs instantly before the specified time i.e. 3:30 PM, though I want it to run on 3:30 PM once per day only.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);    
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Date date = cal.getTime();
timer.schedule(timerTask, date, 1000*60*60*24); // once per day
```

Comment: Do *not* use `TimerTask` for this. Your process will be terminated long before the day has elapsed. Use `AlarmManager`.

Comment: But I am changing the specified time dynamically and getting it from database, how will I get the new time as my alarm manager gets started in activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other community users suggested, don't use Timertask, [android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) has a
`AlarmManager`

that you can use.

## HOW?

1. Register the alarm manager with a broadcast receiver, there override the onReceive method (what to do when the alamr is fired)
2. Set the alarm with the interval daily and the time to be executed.

---

Here a Snippet as Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG ="MainActivity";
PendingIntent myPendingIntent;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver;
Calendar firingCal;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Register AlarmManager Broadcast receive.
    firingCal= Calendar.getInstance();
    firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8); // At the hour you want to fire the alarm
    firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // alarm minute 
    firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // and alarm second
    long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
    
    registerMyAlarmBroadcast();
    alarmManager.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , myPendingIntent );
}
 
private void registerMyAlarmBroadcast()
{
      Log.i(TAG, "Going to register Intent.RegisterAlramBroadcast");

    //This is the call back function(BroadcastReceiver) which will be call when your 
    //alarm time will reached.
    myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"BroadcastReceiver::OnReceive()");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Your Alarm is there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.alarm.example") );
    myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.alarm.example"),0 );
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
}
private void UnregisterAlarmBroadcast()
{
    alarmManager.cancel(myPendingIntent); 
    getBaseContext().unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

---

## Edit:

if the time can changed dynamically in the App depending on user-inputs, then just change the Calender firingCal variable for adjusting the time.

Comment: But time is not fixed, it's getting changed dynamically in my app.

Comment: @ZeeshanAliSayyed, ok tnxs for the clarification, I update the answer

Comment: Hi @Xoce, What if device is rebooted or turned off and turned on again.