# Set alarm through android AlarmClock class in BACKGROUND

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarm

I am making an app and setting alarm is one of the feature. I don't need the app to be a stand alone alarm manager for now. So, I am setting alarm through [AlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) class's ACTION_SET_ALARM using the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);
i.putExtra(ALarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Good Morning");
startActivity(i);
```

It works fine fulfilling the requirement. But my app opens the system's default clock post setting the alarm automatically on button press. I don't need this to happen.
I need to press the button, the alarm needs to set (which is happening now too) but i don't need the system's clock app to show up. I have seen some apps do what i require.

Kindly help me in setting alarm in background / not open the clock app after setting the alarm.
Hope i have conveyed my question clear.

Comment: I have not used AlarmClock until now, but as far as I can see in the API, it´s the default behaviour. You have to make an activity that opens on that intent. Maybe you can make a simple activiy and close it directly if you don´t want to open one.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html

Comment: I hope this may help you! [AlarmManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703898/schedule-a-timertask-at-specific-time-once-per-day-in-a-service-in-android)

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I tried closing the activity as well as returning to the activity where i press a button to set alarm. But as soon as the above lines are executed, the rest of the code goes out of scope since the control is transferred to a completely different app (system's default clock app).

Comment: @zeeali Thank you for the share. But the thread suggests to use alarmManager which i am doing now. The code suggested is useful for making the app a standalone alarm app using broadcastReceiver (start activity on alarm time, dismiss, snooze etc). I don't want to bring in all those functionalities now. Right now, i need to set alarm on button click through the android system itself. And let the system handle cancel, snooze etc., which is happening but opening the clock app after setting the alarm (through button press).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a way by reading the API :). You have to use EXTRA_SKIP_UI set to true.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Good Morning");
    startActivity(i);
```

like stated out in the API

> If true, the application is asked to bypass any intermediate UI. If
>   false, the application may display intermediate UI like a confirmation
>   dialog or settings.

I tested it by myself and if using this EXTRA, it has prompted a Toast that the alarm is set without using any other app.

### EDIT

Just for completeness, You need to add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"></uses-permission>
```

I first forgot to set this permission, and to my surprise it worked nevertheless in emulator, but crashed in device.

Comment: Ahh! I wonder how i missed that while reading the documentation. Thank you. It worked!