# How to make android service run every day once

Tags: android, service

I have a service that runs well but when phone goes to deep sleep , the service stop working .

I want to make use of some android class that makes the service to run everyday 
at specific time ,??

i have tried wakelock but it drains the battery very fast for 24/24 cpu on

Any HELP ??

Comment: Use a JobScheduler?

Comment: mmm but what if i use alarmmanger , is it good or JobScheduler ?
@0X0nosugar

Comment: Or is there a mean to wake the service everyday once ???
@0X0nosugar

Comment: I suppose my search engine is well trained by now, so "JobScheduler android" gave me [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)

Comment: Check out this link, I believe it may be a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703898/schedule-a-timertask-at-specific-time-once-per-day-in-a-service-in-android

Comment: hhh yeah dude but my minSdkVersion=8
Alarmmanger i think is a good way for the service

Comment: @Sam thanks man , but is broadcast receiver is Necessary ??

Comment: Yes that is how you get notified from another app broadcast notification. aka job scheduler or network change or any other number of Android com pipelines. It's not that bad, it's just one java file named after your broadcast Receiver, register in your manifest (unless it's required in code, some are now with latest Android) then schedule your reocurring job and sit back. Set it for 1 minute for trial until you are good, Then change and deploy to 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this becomes a bigger discussion then our comments. I'll list my answer here.

So your goal is to schedule a job with the alarm manager. Just make yourself a broadcast receiver class and register it on your app's startup. Then you will get code to run on each received notification.

If you need your service to run one time use an IntentService for efficiency instead of regular service.

Also, if you need to make sure it starts automatically then you should register for receiving of phone boot so that you can start your scheduled job again.

The link example:
[Schedule a TimerTask at specific time once per day in a service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703898/schedule-a-timertask-at-specific-time-once-per-day-in-a-service-in-android)

Comment: but does the broadcast receiver wake the cpu or drain the battery until the alarm is on ??

Comment: A broadcast receiver is just a means to listen. Think of it like this. Android has a walkie talkie with many channels. On channel 123 they are broadcasting alarm manager notifications. Now when you sign up you supply a filter as well, let's call that the sub filter (8) for example. So when you register a receiver you are basically turning on your walkie talkie and listening on channel 123 with frequency 8 (aka your package name). So your app will only hear things intended for it. It is very light and does not keep your app awake, it is registering to Android that you want to wake up for this.

Comment: Then you have the PendingIntent, this is like lending out your badge card to get in an office building. It is basically saying you may launch me with this badge card so I have whatever permissions and security that I need. So Android sees you are listening for 123 (8), hears a message for that on timer 24 hours, wakes your app up, calls onRecieve of your registered receiver using PendingIntent and let's you do work from there. Then you go back to sleep until next call to wake. No battery is wasted when you are not awake.

Comment: Broadcast receivers are powerful tool for pub/sub modeling as well as subscribing to powerful updates from the Android Framework that you would otherwise not have access to. You may also build your own custom one and register to be woke up like in this example with your own receiver. I highly recommend you do a sample app and familiarize yourself with them. They are used in almost every single application if your app is written correctly. from knowing if "internet lost, bluetooth disabled, gps enabled, phone call interrupted, all important listeners to improve your app handlings.

Comment: If you aren't using broadcast receivers you really should ask yourself if you have properly QAed the app for all niche cases of battery died, phone stopped, phone call happened, internet flickered, gps changes etc.. as likely you will get undesired behaviors if you are not monitoring the things that matter to your app. If you are doing API call or processing data and lose internet you may end up out of sync or bad data for example. It's important to know these things.

Comment: No problem :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution: you can use any of them alarm manager/jobscheduler/GCMNetworkManager

Create a alarm with looping every 24 hr interval.

That's all you need.

PS: Service will drain your battery.