# How can I disable my Button after one click and enable it after 24 hours or on a Next Date?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, buttonclick

How can I disable my Button after one click and enable it after 24 hours or on a Next Date? I am new to Android.

This is my code:

```
public class ShareDetailActivitySW extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private btn_share_sw;
  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_detail);

        btn_share_sw = findViewById(R.id.btn_share_sw);


        // Please do change in my code I will copy it 
        // This is the button to disable 

        btn_share_sw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name));
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, AppLink);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"), INSTALLCODE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Thanks for sharing your code, but we'd all benefit if you tell us what you've attempted and what problem you are currently having.

Comment: i didn't attempted anything , i want to know how to disable my button after it get clicked and enable it on next day from current day

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? The first heading is "Search and Research". This site doesn't leave questions like this one open long if the poster doesn't appear to have done any research or tried anything. It's very likely this question will be closed because of that. Since you admit you haven't attempted anything it seems likely you haven't done any research.

Answer (score 0):

Inside onClick():

1. Save the current timestamp using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) API.
2. Create an alarm using [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) API ([set()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) or [setExact()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) based on your use case).

Inside onCreate():

Check if the interval between the saved timestamp and current timestamp is greater then a day. If yes, enable the button; else disable it.

Also register a broadcast receiver to receive the set alarms ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35704723/14497159)). When the set alarm is received, enable the button.

If you want to survive a reboot, you might want to restart the set alarm ([link](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#boot)).

The usage of AlarmManager is to make sure the button state updates even if the user is in the ShareDetailActivitySW and if the elapsed time crosses a day. If you don't do this, the button state changes only if user restarts the activity either by restarting the app or navigating to other activity and navigating back to ShareDetailActivitySW.